# nsubstitute received called with specific object argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public myArguments
{
    public List<string> argNames {get; set;}
}
```

In my test I'm doing this:

```
var expectedArgNames = new List<string>();
expectedArgNames.Add("test");

_mockedClass.CheckArgs(Arg.Any<myArguments>()).Returns(1);

_realClass.CheckArgs();

_mockedClass.Received().CheckArgs(Arg.Is<myArguments>(x => x.argNames.Equals(expectedArgNames));
```

But the test fails with this error message:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive a call matching:
    CheckArgs(myArguments)
Actually received no matching calls.
Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):
    CheckArgs(*myArguments*)
```

I'm guessing it's because of the `.Equals()` but I'm not sure how to solve it?

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12699199/390819) a good solution?

Comment: @w0lf yes and no, I think it will work but I'm probably going to have to implement `IEquatable` because the `List<>` can be a list of other object types besides `string`, thanks

Comment: Why did you mix up `_realClass` and `_mockedClass`? I don't see code that calls `CheckArgs()` with `expectedArgNames` variable. Could you post **reproducible** code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your test, you're comparing a `myArguments` class with `List<string>`.

You should either compare the `myArguments.argNames` with the `List<string>` or implement the `IEquatable<List<string>>` in `myArguments`.

Besides, when you are comparing `List<T>`, you should use the `SequenceEquals`instead of `Equals`.

The first option would be:

```
_mockedClass.Received().CheckArgs(
    Arg.Is<myArguments>(x => x.argNames.SequenceEqual(expectedArgNames)));
```

The second would be:

```
public class myArguments : IEquatable<List<string>>
{
    public List<string> argNames { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(List<string> other)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(argNames, other))
            return true;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(argNames, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        return argNames.SequenceEqual(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the second option the test would look like this: `x.ArgNames.Equals(expectedArgNames)` right?, and yes I forgot to include the `x.argNames.Equals`.

Comment: No, with the second option you'd have ```x.Equals```.

Comment: For anyone curious about how to extend the first option solution to multiple arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316858/3905007